# How to setup working directory in VS Code for pylint?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylint

I have a project with that structure:

```
├── .git
├── .gitignore
├── README.md
├── requirements.txt
└── src
```

Pylint by default running from project root and I have error on all my imports, because source root in `src` directory. 
I try to setup the linter path in settings.json, but then linter don't work

```
"python.linting.pylintPath": "cd src && pylint"
```

Question is: how to change the source root for pylint in VS Code? I use this extension https://github.com/DonJayamanne/pythonVSCode

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can solve this by creating a `.env` file in the project root with content:

```
PYTHONPATH=./src
```

Comment: This clearly doesn't work *unless* you `export PYTHONPATH=./src` in the terminal.

Comment: @gented not even when you set pyenv path in workspace settings?

Comment: With the current VS Code Python extension, you *do not* need to run `export PYTHONPATH=./src` if you have a `.env` file with the above contents in your workspace folder. The extension will automatically use any environment variables set in the `.env` file. [See the docs for more info.](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_environment-variable-definitions-file)

Comment: This works for me but not when I run a file in VScode. Any hints there?

Answer (score 9):

Add this line in your `settings.json` file (in the `.vscode` directory).

```
"python.autoComplete.extraPaths": ["./src"],
```

Comment: In case you want to find this through GUI => go to Settings => Extensions => Python => "Auto Complete: Extra Paths" => Edit in settings.json (hopefuly in future this will change to GUI dynamic list of input fields :) )

Answer (score 1):

With the newer separate Pylint VSCode extension, the only thing that worked for me was adding `"pylint.args": ["--rcfile=PATH_TO/pylintrc"]` to my VSCode `settings.json`.

Answer (score -1):

The `PYTHONPATH` is the path to `python`, not the working directory .

The better way is to customize `Settings.json` and `launch.json`, do like this:

```
// vi .vscode/Settings.json
{
    "python.pythonPath": "venv/bin/python",
    "python.linting.pylintEnabled": true,
    "python.linting.enabled": true,
    "python.formatting.provider": "autopep8"
}
```

```
// vi .vscode/launch.json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: your project name",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}/src",
        }
    ]
}
```

refer: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_launch-versus-attach-configurations

Comment: No, `PYTHONPATH` is the list of directories where Python looks for modules. [See the docs.](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH)